# Android: change the main activity background color using spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-layout

THIS IS THE ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <Spinner
>         android:layout_margin="150dp"
>         android:id="@+id/spinner1"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:entries="@array/colors_array"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

THIS IS THE STRING.XML

> ```
> <string name="app_name">ITMA133QUIZ</string>
> <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
> <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
>
> <string-array name="colors_array">
>     <item>Red</item>
>     <item>Orange</item>
>     <item>Yellow</item>
>     <item>Green</item>
>     <item>Blue</item>
>     <item>Violet</item>
> </string-array>
> ```

The output should be when you pick an item on spinner the background of the Activity should change...

I dont know how to code it in java....

Answer (score 1):

```
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors_array));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                   switch(position){
                      case 0: View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
                      view.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
                      break;
                      and so on.....
                   }
            }
        }
```

NOTE that this assumes that you have your color in **R.array folder** no in your values -> strings.xml

Comment: if you found this answer helpfull please mark it as correct answer :/